# Invoke a workflow from Apex Class

Tags: apex, workflow, scheduled-apex

I have a workflow that needs to be run daily to check is the status of a particular file is completed or not. If the file is not completed then the workflow should be triggered and a Email alert should be sent to the user.

I checked if the above scenario could be accomplished in a workflow alone, but it was not possible. So I thought a scheduled Apex class could be used. But the problem now is can a workflow be triggered from an Apex class? If so can someone please tell me how?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a Task associated with the file?

Comment: I'am trying to send a email notification by using an email template at a scheduled time

Comment: If there's a Task assigned to complete the file you mention, then workflow could be presumably be triggered off the Task's status changing to `completed` which then adds it to your email notification queue to be run as a batch (assuming you want to run it as a batch rather than as individual emails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a workflow rules can be triggered from a scheduled/batched class, but you may as well just send the email directly through Apex Code-- you'll save the possibility of validation rules, etc possibly preventing the email from sending. Also, you'll have to actually update the record, which will affect the Last Modified By/Date fields, which may not be your intent.

Triggering the workflow is as simple as making a qualifying update to the record(s) that should be triggered. You could even just update all records everywhere and let whatever happens happen, but that'd be a poor practice for large data sets.

An example scheduler might look like:

```
public class TriggerUpdates implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, SObject[] records) {
        Database.update(records, false); // allow partial success
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) 
        // Nothing to do
    }
}
```

This works simply because workflows evaluate each time a DML occurs, even if no fields were actually modified. The only change that needs to be made to the above code is to add to the query.

If you wanted to be more specific, you could also set a special field on the record that would be set by this code, then key the workflow off of that field (and have it reset the field each time it's done).

Comment: Thanks... but this would pose a problem rite. Say if I had 10 workflows and if i were to use this above method, all the 10 workflows would be triggered rite?

Comment: If the records met the criteria for all the rules, then, yes, all rules would Fire. That's why I recommend using pure Apex Code to send the emails.